# Python datetime: How to add an estimated time to a datet

Tags: python-3.x

I am working with datetime for the first time and am having a specific issue with understanding how to add an estimated time of travel to a user input departure time.  I am stuck.  The problem is my lack of understanding how to add the calculated time to the departure time.  I have tried several things, but am not grasping the logic of datetime.  Here is what I have:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
from datetime import time


depart_date_input = input("Estimated departure date 
(YYYY/MM/DD): ")
depart_time_input = input("Estimated departure time 
(HH:MM AM/PM) : ")
miles = 600
mph = 60

depart_date = datetime.strptime(depart_date_input, 
"%Y/%m/%d")
depart_time = datetime.strptime(depart_time_input, 
"%I:%M %p")

depart_info = datetime(depart_date.year, 
depart_date.month, depart_date.day, depart_time.hour, 
depart_time.minute)
travel_minutes = datetime(miles / mph / 60)
travel_minutes = datetime(travel_minutes.minute)
arrival_datetime = depart_info + travel_minutes

print(depart_date)
print(depart_time)
print(depart_info)
print(arrival_datetime)
```

CORRECTED:
    from datetime import datetime
    from datetime import date
    from datetime import time
    from datetime import timedelta

```
depart_date_input = input("Estimated departure date (YYYY/MM/DD): ")
depart_time_input = input("Estimated departure time (HH:MM AM/PM) : ")
miles = 600
mph = 60
travel_minutes = timedelta(minutes=(miles / mph * 60))

depart_date = datetime.strptime(depart_date_input, "%Y/%m/%d")
depart_time = datetime.strptime(depart_time_input, "%I:%M %p")

depart_info = datetime(depart_date.year, depart_date.month, depart_date.day, 
depart_time.hour, depart_time.minute)
arrival_datetime = depart_info + travel_minutes

print(depart_date)
print(depart_time)
print(depart_info)
print(arrival_datetime)
```

Comment: Travel time is not `datetime` (When you say "It takes 40 minutes", what year is it? Exactly.), but [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects), which represents time durations. Adding two datetimes makes no sense; adding a datetime and a timedelta produces a new datetime as one would expect.

Comment: AHHH! Thank you so much Amadan! And thank you for letting me find the minute error on my own.  I played with timedelta for a bit, but you gave me the confidence to bring it back.

Comment: Great. Now you actually answered your question yourself - so put it not in the question but in an answer, and accept it. \o/